# How to use a String value to reference a List(Of String) in VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, radio-button, selection

Using VB.Net 4.6 (VS Enterprise 2015), Window Forms

**I have the following scenario:**

1. I have four `List(Of String)`s named 'BlackRed', 'BlackGreen',
   'WhiteRed' & 'WhiteGreen'.
2. I have two GroupBoxes, each with two
   RadioButtons. `GroupBox1` is 'Shirt Color' with `RadioButtons` 'Black' &
   'White' and `GroupBox2` is 'Pants Color' with `RadioButtons` 'Red' &
   'Green'.

   Depending on what RadioButtons are checked, I end up with a
   String variable named 'ColorCombo' that contains the chosen colors.

   The four possibilities being "BlackRed", "BlackGreen", "WhiteRed" or
   "WhiteGreen" are the same as the names of my four List(Of String)s.
3. I have one Chart that uses the variable `ListToChart` (which is
   a `List(Of String)`) to plot data.

**Now my question is:**

How can I use the value in the
    String variable to assign the matching `List(Of String)` as
    'ListToChart'? I can't use
        ListToChart = ColorCombo as that obviously leads to a "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to `List(Of String)`" error.

**For example:** 'Shirt Color' is Black, 'Pants Color' is Red. This
    creates a value of "BlackRed" in the String variable named
    'ColorCombo'. I'd now like to assign the `List(Of String)` that has
    the same name as the value in 'ColorCombo' to the variable
    'ListToChart'.

The following is a modified version of my code:

```
Public Class Form2
Public Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'The Lists are populated on another form and carried over to this one.
    'The actual code consists of about 40 Lists and about 15 RadioButtons. This code is an extremely stripped down version.
    'Assume for this example, the 4 List(Of String)s are named BlackRed, BlackGreen, WhiteRed & WhiteGreen.
    Call READRADIOBUTTONS()
End Sub
Public Sub READRADIOBUTTONS()
    If RadioButtonShirtBlack.Checked = True Then SHIRTSTRING = "Black"
    If RadioButtonShirtWhite.Checked = True Then SHIRTSTRING = "White"

    If RadioButtonPantsRed.Checked = True Then PANTSSTRING = "Red"
    If RadioButtonPantsGreen.Checked = True Then PANTSSTRING = "Green"

    COLORCOMBO = SHIRTSTRING & PANTSSTRING
    Call PLOTCHARTDATA()
End Sub
Public Sub PLOTCHARTDATA()
    'The following line is where I would need to use the String named COLORCOMBO to reference 1 of the 4 List(Of String)s.
    LISTTOCHART = COLORCOMBO

    ChartColors.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()
    For a = 0 To LISTTOCHART.Count - 1
        ChartColors.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(LISTTOCHART.Item(a), COUNTTOCHART(a))
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub RadioButtonShirtBlack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonShirtBlack.Click
    Call READRADIOBUTTONS()
End Sub
Public Sub RadioButtonShirtWhite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonShirtWhite.Click
    Call READRADIOBUTTONS()
End Sub
Public Sub RadioButtonPantsRed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonPantsRed.Click
    Call READRADIOBUTTONS()
End Sub
Public Sub RadioButtonPantsGreen(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonPantsGreen.Click
    Call READRADIOBUTTONS()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this. You should use an Enum to define your Shirts and Pants rather than comparing strings:

```
Public Enum ShirtColour
    Black
    Red
End Enum

Public Enum PantsColour
    White
    Green
End Enum
```

Then you should set a variable based on your radio button selection and use a class to hold the selection:

```
Public Class UserSelection
    Public Property Shirt As ShirtColour
    Public Property Pants As PantsColour
End Class


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim selection As New UserSelection

        If radShirtBlack.Checked Then
            selection.Shirt = ShirtColour.Black
        ElseIf radShirtRed.Checked Then
            selection.Shirt = ShirtColour.Red
        End If

        If radPantsGreen.Checked Then
            selection.Pants = PantsColour.Green
        ElseIf radPantsWhite.Checked Then
            selection.Pants = PantsColour.White
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll have to look further into this and adapt it to my needs, but you definitely gave me a place to start!

Comment: After reviewing this code, although it may have addressed a better way to handle the RadioButton selections, I can't see how this answers the original question. How does this new code allow me to assign one of the four List(Of String)s to the 'ListToChart' variable, based on the overall combinations of the RadioButtons?

Comment: It doesn't (but it was too long for a comment). Your design is poor, so I have pointed you in a better direction. Having said that; you just need to use the `selection` to plot your chart now instead of a `List(of String)`. Without seeing the code for this I can't give you any more help on how to do this.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to minimize/barebone my code as much as possible and paste a bit of it when I get a chance. Thanks again for taking the time to help out.